# Не запускается ZooKeeper на win 10

Tags: windows-10

Распаковал архив с ZooKeeper, все по инструкции, настроил конфигурционный файл.
При запуске в консоли zkServer получал следующее:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    ... 12 more

Unable to start AdminServer, exiting abnormally
2020-10-28 15:07:35,644 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZKAuditProvider@42] - ZooKeeper audit is disabled.
2020-10-28 15:07:35,647 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ServiceUtils@42] - Exiting JVM with code 4
```

Погуглил, посмотрел чем занят порт - ничем, его нет в списке занятых, все равно подменил его к конфигурационном файле. После этого при запуске zkServer получаю:

```
2020-10-28 15:31:10,772 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@339] - Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 clientPortListenBacklog -1 datadir C:Program Filesapache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin\version-2 snapdir C:Program Filesapache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin\version-2
2020-10-28 15:31:10,817 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Log@169] - Logging initialized @802ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2020-10-28 15:31:10,927 [myid:] - WARN  [main:ContextHandler@1520] - o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6221a451{/,null,UNAVAILABLE} contextPath ends with /*
2020-10-28 15:31:10,928 [myid:] - WARN  [main:ContextHandler@1531] - Empty contextPath
2020-10-28 15:31:10,962 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Server@359] - jetty-9.4.24.v20191120; built: 2019-11-20T21:37:49.771Z; git: 363d5f2df3a8a28de40604320230664b9c793c16; jvm 11.0.9+11-LTS
2020-10-28 15:31:11,016 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DefaultSessionIdManager@333] - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-10-28 15:31:11,016 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DefaultSessionIdManager@338] - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-10-28 15:31:11,020 [myid:] - INFO  [main:HouseKeeper@140] - node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-10-28 15:31:11,031 [myid:] - WARN  [main:ConstraintSecurityHandler@757] - ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6221a451{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /*
2020-10-28 15:31:11,045 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ContextHandler@825] - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6221a451{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-10-28 15:31:11,473 [myid:] - INFO  [main:AbstractConnector@330] - Started ServerConnector@73e22a3d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8082}
2020-10-28 15:31:11,474 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Server@399] - Started @1459ms
2020-10-28 15:31:11,475 [myid:] - INFO  [main:JettyAdminServer@182] - Started AdminServer on address 0.0.0.0, port 8082 and command URL /commands
2020-10-28 15:31:11,482 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@169] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
2020-10-28 15:31:11,484 [myid:] - WARN  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@309] - maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0.
2020-10-28 15:31:11,486 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@666] - Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 8 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers.
2020-10-28 15:31:11,490 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@674] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2020-10-28 15:31:11,509 [myid:] - INFO  [main:WatchManagerFactory@42] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManager as watch manager
2020-10-28 15:31:11,510 [myid:] - INFO  [main:WatchManagerFactory@42] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManager as watch manager
2020-10-28 15:31:11,512 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZKDatabase@132] - zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33
2020-10-28 15:31:11,512 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZKDatabase@152] - zookeeper.commitLogCount=500
2020-10-28 15:31:11,521 [myid:] - INFO  [main:SnapStream@61] - zookeeper.snapshot.compression.method = CHECKED
2020-10-28 15:31:11,522 [myid:] - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@470] - Snapshotting: 0x0 to C:Program Filesapache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin\version-2\snapshot.0
2020-10-28 15:31:11,539 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZKDatabase@289] - Snapshot loaded in 26 ms, highest zxid is 0x0, digest is 1371985504
2020-10-28 15:31:11,540 [myid:] - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@470] - Snapshotting: 0x0 to C:Program Filesapache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin\version-2\snapshot.0
2020-10-28 15:31:11,553 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@529] - Snapshot taken in 14 ms
2020-10-28 15:31:11,564 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@136] - PrepRequestProcessor (sid:0) started, reconfigEnabled=false
2020-10-28 15:31:11,565 [myid:] - INFO  [main:RequestThrottler@74] - zookeeper.request_throttler.shutdownTimeout = 10000
2020-10-28 15:31:11,587 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ContainerManager@83] - Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000 maxNeverUsedIntervalMs=0
2020-10-28 15:31:11,589 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZKAuditProvider@42] - ZooKeeper audit is disabled.
```

На этом моменте зависает и все.

Comment: @gil9red исправил.

Comment: А это все логи? Нет в них ошибок -- только INFO

Comment: @gil9red были warnings, добавил в логи

Comment: Погуглил текст из WARN `Empty contextPath` и нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437233/zookeeper-starting-on-incorrect-port Возможно это поможет

Comment: @gil9red это оносилось к предыдущей ошибке, которая в первых логах, там я порт менял, тут не помогает.